# git-svn: How to prevent "dcommit", "rebase" when not on master

Tags: git-svn

I am using `git-svn`.

My problem is, I **never** want to be able to do a `git svn rebase` or even worse a `git svn dcommit` while I am on a local branch. I **only** want to do this while I am on the `master` branch.

How I can make sure that `git` prevents these operations ?

I tried to give dummies via `git config branch.<name>.remote` but this does not help for `git svn rebase` and `git svn dcommit`.

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An other idea would go like this.

```sh
function git () {
  if [[ "$1" = svn ]] && [[ "$2" =~ dcommit|rebase ]]; then
    # allow git-svn dcommit/rebase only on master
    if git branch --show-current | grep -q master; then
      echo "Master branch check passed" >&2
      command git "$@"
    else
      echo "Disallowed - not on master" >&2
      return 1
    fi
  else
    # subcommand filter passthrough
    command git "$@"
  fi
}
```

This shadows `/usr/bin/git` with a `bash` function named `git` — all it does is detecting the commands you want to disallow to yourself, and passing them through (or not) to the real executable (`command git`).

Comment: Ok that's for sure not what I was looking for; but at least it's an idea which will work :) Thank you.